# How to fix this wordpress css3 problems

Tags: wordpress, css

I created a website, but having some problem with header menu. the dropdown is not working in Internet explorer 9. here is the website address: http://thankgodforplexus.com/

& here is the css for the navigation: http://pastebin.com/jWZJASHL

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the position relative  from below css it will work in ie9. Corrected [**Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/9FQCA/)

```
.header-nav {
        /* Layout & positioning */
        display: block;
        /*position: relative;*/
        margin: 10px auto 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 43px;
        width: 870px;
        list-style: none;
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        z-index: 1000;

        /* Background */
        background: #e777b1; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e777b1 0%, #e0548f 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e777b1), color-stop(100%,#e0548f)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e777b1 0%,#e0548f 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #e777b1 0%,#e0548f 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #e777b1 0%,#e0548f 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e777b1 0%,#e0548f 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e777b1', endColorstr='#e0548f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

Comment: thanks, but if I remove the position relative, then the z-index value not works any more. see http://thankgodforplexus.com/

Comment: Do the following changes in your css and let me know whether is it working or not.
.header-nav > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.slider {
    border: 5px solid #E05590;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}

Comment: already fixed it by adding z-index to the dropdown menu. but thank you very very much. You made my day! I was so tensed about this. thank you so much!